# Adding +1 to jQuery value of a readonly text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function where I have a `readonly` text `input`, and when I execute the function I want the number value + 1. So let's say I have 60, when I execute the function, the number returned should be 61.

But instead it's coming out 601, which is just adding the number 1 to the string. Any clue as to what is going on? Subtraction, multiplication and division all work fine. Here is a snippet

```
 var num= $("#originalnum").val() + 1;
 $("#originalnum").val(num);
```

And yes i've tried a few different variations, am I missing something?

Comment: Use an `<input type="number">` :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A simple unary `+` is sufficient to turn a string into a number in this case:

```
var num = +$("#originalnum").val() + 1;
$("#originalnum").val(num);
```

Comment: 1+ the + operator is to a variable indicatiing its a number is alot faster then the parseInt(x,10) (when used to it)

Comment: so when i use the + sign in front of lets say a span or text input im indicating that its not a string but that its an int?

Comment: not that i can really see a difference, but in cases where i use it for phonegap and stuff (and because its probably better practice etc) i like this answer

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that `.val()` returns the value of the element as a string, and when you use the `+` operator on a string it does string concatenation. You need to convert the value to a number first:

```
var num = +$("#originalnum").val() + 1;            // unary plus operator
// OR
var num = Number($("#originalnum").val()) + 1;     // Number()
// OR
var num= parseFloat($("#originalnum").val()) + 1;  // parseFloat()
// OR
var num= parseInt($("#originalnum").val(),10) + 1; // parseInt()
```

Note that if you use `parseInt()` you *must* include the radix (10) as the second parameter or it will (depending on the browser) treat strings with a leading zero as octal and strings with a leading `"0x"` as hexadecimal. Note also that `parseInt()` ignores any non-numeric characters at the end of the string, including a full-stop that the user might have intended as a decimal point, so `parseInt("123.45aasdf",10)` returns `123`. Similarly `parseFloat()` ignores non-numeric characters at the end of the string.

Also if it's a user-entered value you should double-check that it actually is a number and perhaps provide an error message if it isn't.

When you use the `*`, `/` or `-` operators JS tries to convert the string to a number automatically, so that's why those operators "work" (assuming the string *can* be converted).

Comment: I like the Number() solution. It's self documenting.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `parseInt` function and make sure the value is number(use isNaN function):

```
var val = $("#originalnum").val();

var num = 0;

if ( !isNaN(val) )
  num= parseInt(val) + 1;
```

Comment: i can use that even if my input box is type text?

Comment: and do by any chance know why every other operation works but addition? ie multiplication division etc?

Comment: It will return NaN if it's not a number

Comment: The other operations probably cause the JS engine to convert the types.  Because `+` is a valid operator for strings, the types are not converted (and the strings are concatenated).

Comment: @Dnaso because + can also mean concat for strings

Comment: Please don't forget to supply `10` as *radix* parameter

Answer (score 5):

Use `parseInt()`:

```
var num= parseInt($("#originalnum").val(),10) + 1;
```

So your number is treated as an integer instead of a string (as `.val()` treats the result as string by default)

Comment: Please don't forget to supply `10` as *radix* parameter

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the above code spelling, you can try it this way too.

```
$("#originalnum").val(function() {
   $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1)
});
```