# Jquery drop down changing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am junior in jquery so not be serios. I want to do simple script which adding 1 to the dropdown list value. I tried many of them by this link:
[Adding +1 to jQuery value of a readonly text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464007/adding-1-to-jquery-value-of-a-readonly-text-input-field)
However that is not helped.That is my script.

```
$('#nextPage').click(function () {
var page = $('#page').val();
$('#page').val(page + 1);
$('#search').submit();
```

});

### Html

```
<form id="search" method="POST" class="ui small form sixteen wide column segment">
```

```
<div class="three wide field">
    <label>Page number</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown" id="dropdown-pages">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="{{ filters.page }}">
        <div class="default text">Limit</div>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
            {% for page in 1..count_pages %}              
                <div class="item" data-value="{{ page }}">{{ page }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="two wide field">
    <label>By one</label>
    {% if filters.page != 1 %}
        <button class="ui submit button"><</button>
    {% endif %}
    {% if filters.page != count_pages %}
        <button class="ui submit button" id='nextPage'>></button>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Search

Clear

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should have been more careful when copying the suggested scripts...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding +1 to jQuery value of a readonly text input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464007/adding-1-to-jquery-value-of-a-readonly-text-input-field)

Comment: In order to help we would need to see the relevant html.

Comment: I used parse number they added1 to my value however after submitting nothing is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var page = parseInt($('#page').val());
$('#page').val(page + 1);
$('#search').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of dropdown-pages by:

```
var page = parseInt($('#dropdown-pages').val())+1;
alert(page);
```

Comment: `val()` of what? the `dropdown()` plugin isn't used on a form control so it would have no `val()`

Comment: that comes NaN result

Comment: ok can you tell what does $('#dropdown-pages').val() is returning? post html here if possible

Comment: I checked nothing returns However I make some changes in code with your methods now its working
var page = parseInt($('#page').val())+1;

Comment: Sir I have one question when I submitting, form just refreshing the value is not chaged